# Drupal form #ajax callback and javascript toggleClass on radio buttons - reduced functionality

Tags: forms, ajax, javascript

we're using drupal and I have setup an ajax callback on a form item. The form item is a radio button with two options on/off. also attached to the radio button is some js to toggle a class. The class will toggle correctly as long as the callback is commented out

Here is a paste of my code:

// Making a call to web service and getting value to determine class

```
<?php
if (($user_alert['endDate'] == $today) || ($user_alert['endDate'] > $today) ) {

$activeFlagClass = $user_alert['activeFlag'];
$active_flag_class = get_active_flag_class($activeFlagClass);

$alerts[] = array(
  'activFlag' => $user_alert['activeFlag'],
  'activeFlagClass' => $active_flag_class,
  'adhMedicationAlertId' => $user_alert['adhMedicationAlertId'],
  );
}
```

// This is the theme template where I am printing the class and calling a form

```
<?php foreach($alerts as $key=>$value): ?>
    <div class="list-alerts-group">
    <!-- printing the php class here -->
      <div class="list-alerts-item <?php print $value['activeFlagClass']; ?>">
      <!-- There are list of variables here including calling a form -->
        <div class="alerts-item alert-active-flag-form-wrapper">
        <?php
        $active = $value['activeFlag'];
        $alertId = $value['adhMedicationAlertId'];
        $alertsActiveFlag = drupal_get_form('innovicares_alerts_active_flag_form', $active, $alertId);
        print drupal_render($alertsActiveFlag);
        ?>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

// This the form with attached js for toggleClass and attached #ajax callback

```
<?php
function innovicares_alerts_active_flag_form($form, &$form_state, $active, $alertId) {
   // Init variables
  $active_flag = '';
  $alert_id = '';

  // Let's define the default value for $active
  if ($active == 'true') {
    $active_flag = 1;
  }

  if ($active == 'false') {
    $active_flag = 0;
  }

  // Toggles alert form based on $active
  $form['#attached']['js'] = array(
    drupal_get_path('module', 'innovicares_alerts') . '/js/alerts.js',
  );

  // krumo($active_flag);

  $form['alert']['active_flag'] = array(
    '#type' => 'radios',
    '#attributes' => array(
      'class' => array(
        'alert-active-flag-radio'
        ),
      ),
    // Get default from callback
    '#default_value' => $active_flag,
    '#options' => array(
      1 => t('ON'), 
      0 => t('OFF')
      ),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'set_active_flag',
      'event' => 'click',
      'progress' => array('type' => 'none'),
      ),
  );

  // Let's define the alert id
  $alert_id = $alertId;

  $form['alert']['alert_id'] = array(
    '#type' => 'hidden',
    '#default_value' => $alert_id,
  );  

  // Return the form
  return $form;
}
```

// This is the #ajax callback

```
function set_active_flag($form, &$form_state) {
  // Init variables
  $current_active_flag ='';
  $active_flag = '';

  $alertId = $form_state['values']['alert_id'];

  $current_active_flag = $form_state['values']['active_flag'];

  if ($current_active_flag == 1) {
    $active_flag = deactivate_active_flag($alertId);
    krumo($active_flag);
  }

  elseif ($current_active_flag == 0) {
    $active_flag = activate_active_flag($alertId);
    // krumo($active_flag['data']['activeFlag']);
    // This is coming back as false

    // $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

    return $active_flag;

  }
}
```